# Fixed centered menu with dynamic height

Tags: css

Probably a stupid question, but is there a way to get dynamic height on a fixed centered menu? Without javascript!

http://jsfiddle.net/Pbyju/31/

What I want:

```
 1. Buttons centered in the header (in the blue area)
 2. Dynamic height (blue area) IF the red area expands.
```

The header must be fixed!

Final results:
http://tinyurl.com/7fzlajo

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you want? I don't get it.

Comment: Are you adding buttons server side or client side?

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/7fzlajo content (ex: buttons) are in server side

Comment: hey did this help at all?? I mean I answered the original question but was not successful with the intent maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I was able to get what you wanted but the top text is getting cut off. Now I am sure you might need it too look something similar to that but all I did was include the buttons in the header and then have the header have a `height:auto;` that seemed to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZcWjy/1/